# Many To One Relation in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Product_info")

public class Product {
    private int ProductIndex;
    private int priority;
    private Date dateTime;
    private String action;
    private String status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="releaseIndex")
    private Release release;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    protected int getProductIndex() {
        return ProductIndex;
    }
    protected void setProductIndex(int ProductIndex) {
        this.ProductIndex = ProductIndex;
    }
    public Release getRelease() {
        return release;
    }
    public void setRelease(Release release) {
        this.release = release;
    }
    /*public Region getRegion() {
        return region;
    }
    public void setRegion(Region region) {
        this.region = region;
    }*/
    @Column(name="priority")
    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
    @Column(name="datetime")
    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }
    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
    @Column(name="action")
    public String getAction() {
        return action;
    }
    public void setAction(String action) {
        this.action = action;
    }
    @Column(name="status")
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Product() {
    }

    public Product(int priority, Date dateTime, String action, String status) {
        this.priority = priority;
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
        this.action = action;
        this.status = status;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name="release")


public class Release {
    private int releaseIndex;
    private String releaseName;
    private Set<ProductInfo> productInfo = new HashSet<ProductInfo>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="id")
    protected int getReleaseIndex() {
        return releaseIndex;
    }
    protected void setReleaseIndex(int releaseIndex) {
        this.releaseIndex = releaseIndex;
    }
    @Column(name="name")
    public String getReleaseName() {
        return releaseName;
    }
    public void setReleaseName(String releaseName) {
        this.releaseName = releaseName;
    }
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="release")
    public Set<ProductInfo> getProductInfo() {
        return ProductInfo;
    }
    public void setProductInfo(Set<ProductInfo> productInfo) {
        this.productInfo = productInfo;
    }
}
```

Above are the two classes i want to create ManytoOne relationship but it gives me error  could not determine type for: dao.Release, at table: product_info, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(release)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You face this error because annotations are inconsistently sometimes in fields and sometimes in methods. If you do not want to play with AccessType, easiest solution is to move annotations from release-field to getRelease method.